# Build and Deploy multiple azure function projects using YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I am trying to build and publish multiple azure function projects within a single solution using YAML pipelines but when I publish the packages they are overwriting each other so I only publish the last project built.

I use these steps to build:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore project dependencies'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: Nuget.config
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build the project - $(configuration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(configuration) -p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions" -p:ArtifactStagingDirectory="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Artifacts"'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish the project - $(configuration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: '**/*Functions.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(configuration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions'
    zipAfterPublish: true
    modifyOutputPath: true

 - publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions'
   displayName: 'Publish drop'
   artifact: functions
```

Is there a way I can publish the functions by project? I tried the VSBuild task to build the solution but when trying to deploy to Azure using the AzureFunctionApp task, it errors out saying msBuild packages are not supported.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a pattern that worked for me. Instead of trying to publish all the projects within my solution with just one task, I split them up and gave each one it's own task. So I went from this:

```yaml
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Functions'
    inputs:
      command: publish
      projects: '**/*.Functions.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: false
      arguments: '--no-build --configuration ${{ variables.configuration }} -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions'
      modifyOutputPath: true
      zipAfterPublish: true
```

to this:

```yaml
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project 1 Functions'
    inputs:
      command: publish
      projects: '**/Project1.Functions.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: false
      arguments: '--no-build --configuration ${{ variables.configuration }} -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions\Project1'
      modifyOutputPath: true
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project2 Functions'
    inputs:
      command: publish
      projects: '**/Project2.Functions.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: false
      arguments: '--no-build --configuration ${{ variables.configuration }} -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions\Project2'
      modifyOutputPath: true
      zipAfterPublish: true
```

I kept the rest of my template the same as in my original post.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Glad to know that you have found the answer. You can accept your answer. This will be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can publish the functions by project?

Based on your description, you have multiple projects in a single solution file.

As far as I know, in Dotnet Publish task, you could set the `publishWebProjects: false`. Then the functions will be published by project.

You could refer to my sample:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(configuration) -p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions" -p:ArtifactStagingDirectory="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Artifacts"'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(configuration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Functions'
    zipAfterPublish: True
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: ' $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's what I'm doing already From the logs, I can see that subsequent projects are overriding the prior ones so only the last one gets published. I don't know if this makes a difference but the projects are Azure functions. 

I was using the [VSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) task before and it builds correctly, but generates msBuild packages which are not supported by the `AzureFunctionApp@1` deployment task.

Comment: I think this is an issue that has been going on for a while 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7779

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [Publish Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact) task you could use [artifact.upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands#upload-upload-an-artifact) logging command to upload multiple artifacts from a single script step:

> #### Upload: Upload an artifact
>
> `##vso[artifact.upload]local file path`
>
> ##### Usage
>
> Upload a local file into a file container folder, and optionally publish an artifact as `artifactname`.
>
> ##### Properties
>
> `containerfolder` = folder that the file will upload to, folder will be created if needed.
> `artifactname` = artifact name. (Required)

#### Example

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Functions' -Filter '*.zip' -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        '##vso[artifact.upload containerfolder={0};artifactname={0}]{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.FullName
    }
  displayName: Publish artifacts
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful to know. But I think the problem is in the dotnet publish task. I looks like the `modifyOutputPath` variable does not work with *.snl files well.